# java locale tags to locale displayname

Tags: java, android, locale

I am trying to convert the locale tags (see picture) to display names. For instance, instead of en-us I would like to display English (USA). So far I have managed to get a mixture of display names and language tags as in the picture:

[device system languages screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ituoD.jpg)

I have tried many thing such as using forLanguageTag, getDisplayLanguage + getDisplayCountry but nothing works.

This is my code snippet:

```
    public void getAvailableLocales() {
    systemLanguages = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
    Arrays.sort(systemLanguages);
    for (int i = 0; i < systemLanguages.length; i++) {
        String sL = systemLanguages[i];
        Locale loc = new Locale(sL);
        String locDisplayResults = loc.getDisplayLanguage();
        languagesList.add(new Languages(locDisplayResults));
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The idea is to display all languages available on a given device.
Any help would be gratefully received.

Edit: Testing shows that Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales() **does** indeed give the languages available for each given device. However, getDisplayLanguage only works for two letter tags, and not for two letters-dash-two letters (eg. ar-eg). Any more ideas?

Comment: So the answer was: [Instead of using new Locale(sL), use Locale.forLanguageTag(sL).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427876/convert-da-dk-to-danish-denmark-etc) It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

for(Locale locale : availableLocales){
    Log.d("Locale", locale.getDisplayName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me all supported locales by Java 8, not my system locales.

Comment: I think the problem with your call to getLocales() is his API Level, which is 24. So maybe your device has a lower API.

Comment: In that case, is there another way of getting the languages that are available on my device? Because I would like my app to be available to more users than just Nougat...

Comment: I think is not posible. I've searched what getLocales() does, and is not going to tell you all installed languages of the device. Instead it will tell you what languages the user has selected, because [in Android N you can select more than one language](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html).