# Convert da-DK to Danish (Denmark) etc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locale

How do I convert locale ids into display languages and countries in Java. For instance, I have a list of locales in this format: "da-DK" and I want them all to show as "Danish (Denmark)".

Here is my code so far:

```
    public void getAvailableLocales() {
    systemLanguages = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
    Arrays.sort(systemLanguages);
    for (int i = 0; i < systemLanguages.length; i++) {
        String sL = systemLanguages[i];
        Locale loc = new Locale(sL);
        String locDisplayResults = loc.getDisplayName();
        languagesList.add(new Languages(locDisplayResults));
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, getDisplayName() is only working for cases where there is just two letters for the language, such as "ar" for "Arabic". It leaves "ar-EG" untouched.

Comment: Can you split them on the dash, pass each individually, and then join the results in your format? Something like `String result = sL.split("-").each(item -> new Locale(item)).join(" (")) + ");`  (I also realize those commands aren't native, but you can achieve them via Observables or something [like this](https://github.com/mattsilber/collection-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/guardanis/collections/tools/ListUtils.java), or just write them out the long way)

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I am not familiar with Observable but I shall look into it.

Comment: Observable might be overkill for this task, but that ListUtils class I linked you to would work with the code I posted, just replace `sL.split("-").each` with `ListUtils.from(sL.split("-")).map` and that code should work out-of-the-box

Comment: Thanks very much, I can't see how to upvote your comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `new Locale(sL)`, use `Locale.forLanguageTag(sL)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)